# Full coverage fenders without chainstay bridge?

Tags: fenders

Is there a way to install full coverage fenders without a chainstay bridge on this bike?

I'm looking at alloy fenders in the style of [velo-orange](https://velo-orange.com/collections/700c-fenders) & [planet bike](https://www.planetbike.com/cascadia-alx-bike-fenders-700c-x-43mm/)'s full coverage fenders as they seem to be able to prevent road spray from hitting the bottom bracket area.

There are fender eyelets near the dropouts and a mounting point on the underneath of the seatstay bridge.

[This idea](https://www.bikeforums.net/12506197-post5.html) using a light mount seems like a good starting place but I don't think the clamp is a good match for the flat shape of this bike's chainstays.

Any idea how I could get the front mounting point of the fenders attached to the bottom bracket area of this bike? Maybe stainless steel P-clamps and an angle bracket?

[image: Rear eyelets]
[image: Seatstay bridge - underneath view]
[image: Seatstay bridge - front view]
[image: Bottom bracket / chainstay area]
[image: Rear triangle]

Answer (score 6):

Totally !

You need the front of the rear mudguard to be at or below the chainstays.  I've 3d-printed a part for this purpose and it worked fine for over a year so far.

Your seat tube is a good clamping point too, but is not quite as good as lower down.   In the past I've formed up a strap from aluminium and wrapped it around the lower end of the seatpost, which was good enough but did tend to rattle.

---

Here's a mock up of my printed bridge.  One has cable/zip tie slots for around the chainstays, the other would just be held in by friction.  Your stays are a much more slab-sided construction, so this isn't an exact fit for your bike.

https://www.tinkercad.com/things/7i0ZWFJGqzQ-chainstay-bridge-for-supporting-a-mudguard

Comment: @scottmeup send me some measurements and I'll mock you up a design.

Answer (score 5):

Giant usually have a bolt on the back of the seat tube instead of a chainstay bridge. In your photos, this could be hidden by the front derailleur. If it is there, you will need to drill a hole in your mudguard in the correct place and use any spacers or washers between the frame & mudguard necessary to get the mudguard the distance from the tyre you want.

If you do not have this mounting point, there are good quality mudguards in the style of the SKS Velo that mount around the seat tube and give good coverage.

At the dropouts, I do not believe the hole circled green is suitable for mounting anything, I see it more as a decorative touch. Holes for mounting things are generally tapped with an M5 thread in this area. You will probably have to share the mounting point with the rear rack or use little P clamps on your rear rack to bolt on the mudguard stays.